# How to create table in clickhouse in the log storage scenario?

Tags: clickhouse

I use clickhouse to store logs, every row in clickhouse will be one log line.

### Query

I will use `where id = 'id_a' order by log_time, offset desc limit 100` to get the latest 100 lines.
Here `log_time` is the time when the log line is collected, and `offset` is the offset of the log line in the origin log file (because we will collect multi lines at
the same time, `offset` is needed to help to order log lines).

### Create Table

I tried to use `CREATE TABLE tableA (id String, log_time DateTime64(3), offset UInt64) PARTITION BY toDate(log_time) PRIMARY KEY id ORDER BY (id, log_time, offset) SETTINGS index_granularity = 4096`.
The log lines will be stored in clickhouse with ascending `log_time, offset` order. However, my query case is `order by log_time, offset desc limit 1000`.

### Question

How could I speed up my query? For example, can I create a table with `ORDER BY (id, log_time, offset) desc`? or can I set an index on the position of the max (log_time,offset) per id so that it can be quickly indexed to the last row.

---

Thanks in advance!